# ¿Como comparar el contenido de un mysqli_fetch_object y un string en php?

Tags: php

¿Como comparar el contenido de un objeto y un string en php?

bueno hasta ahora tengo esta comparación

```
     $sql ="SELECT tUsuario FROM usuarios where Usuario='".$_POST['usuario']."' AND clave='".$_POST['contraseña']."'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
            var_dump($resultado);
            $row =mysqli_fetch_object($resultado);
            var_dump($row);
         $filas=count($resultado);
        if ($filas>0) {
            $var1 = "Administrador";
            $var2="Usuario";
            //Aqui es donde la comparación se confunde y he estado 
              //buscando metodos para solucionarlo y que la comparación funcione como debería hacerlo
    if ($row === $var1) {
            echo '<script> window.location="Administrador.php";</script>';
            }elseif ($row === $var2) {
                echo '<script> window.location="Usuario.php";</script>';
            }
```

pero no comprendo la razón por la que se 
confunde

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas comparando un objeto con un string y eso no es valido.  La forma correcta seria:

```
$sql ="SELECT tUsuario FROM usuarios where Usuario='".$_POST['usuario']."' AND clave='".$_POST['contraseña']."'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
var_dump($resultado);
$row =mysqli_fetch_object($resultado);
var_dump($row);
$filas=count($resultado);
if ($filas>0) {
    $var1 = "Administrador";
    $var2="Usuario";
    //Aqui es donde la comparación se confunde y he estado 
    //buscando metodos para solucionarlo y que la comparación funcione como debería hacerlo
    if ($row->tUsuario == $var1) {
        echo '<script> window.location="Administrador.php";</script>';
    } elseif ($row->tUsuario == $var2) {
        echo '<script> window.location="Usuario.php";</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias, ya ha funcionado

Comment: bueno al realizar la condición como la especificaste ahora solo entra a la segunda donde debe ser igual a Usuario y al tratar de acceder con un usuario administrador marca este error  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Probablemente es porque tu query no retorna nada.  Para obtener el numero de filas, en lugar de usar count, debes usar num_rows `if($resultado && $resultado->num_rows > 0) {`